# How to integrate Reporting Services in my SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed a new instance of SQL Server since the old one was damaged by my Avast firewall (can't connect to it anymore). But when installing the new one I couldn't install reporting services that I will use later on ! :(

What shall I do? Is there any possibility to have an extension or some thing like that?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

When you run SQL Server setup did you also select Reporting Services? Run setup again and select modify existing install and select SSRS. It should install.

Comment: Hi "benjamin", in fact I did select it of course but it failed to install and can't catch the reason behind it !! but I'll try it again anyway !

Comment: Are you using SQL Express?